# Websocket STOMP ConnectionLostException in spring boot API

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, java-websocket

Seeing the below exception in my application more frequently, tried increasing the send-buffer-size and inbound message size but still same issue. Looking for options to fix this issue.

2024-01-17 18:40:34.613 DEBUG 18812 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : **StandardWebSocketSession[id=8c3c02be-d8e0-15ba-64c2-7bc04dbe5c55, uri=null] closed with CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages]**

2024-01-17 18:40:34.613 DEBUG 18812 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : **Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=8c3c02be-d8e0-15ba-64c2-7bc04dbe5c55, uri=null]**

**Thanks In Advance**